# Macrium backup and rescue disk creation

Tags: backup, restore, ghost-image, macrium

I am in the process of backing up my PC using "Macrium backup and restore". I have successfully backed my PC, (both C and D drive) to an external hard disk.

I have a question regarding creating rescue disks. I am following the steps as mentioned in [this](http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50033.aspx?Keywords=restore) document. If I am creating an ISO file based on the document, how it is relates to the backup I have taken to my external disk ? I see no relation between creating rescue disks and backup data or am I missing something obvious?

Any insight will be highly appreciable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot CD you are creating from ISO is for purpose of recovering from your backup, if your system for example not booting or you wan't to restore whole system not only data.

You just plug-in cd and recovery system will boot from it and allows you to recover whole disk (if you have it in backup). "It's like a ladder for chopping a tree branch. It's a safe and easy way to do it." :)

Comment: Boot CD which is nothing rescue.iso will be used for restore complete system in case of system failure or virus attack right? Backup I have taken to external hard disk is about 24GB and and the ISO image will be burned i.e. rescue.iso is only 12MB. So ISO doesn't have the backed up data, am I right? I am doing the right thing or missing something? I know these are elementary questions for others, for me I am confused little bit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. CD has nothing to do with your data, it's just a tool to restoration.

Comment: So when I restore my CD(rescue.iso) will be restore complete backed up data? Or after restore I need to install Macrium and restore the data from backed up external hard disk? Thanks

Comment: Well, sort of. You'll put a CD in drive, reboot PC, select boot from that CD, then it'll guide you through restoring process. You'll have to connect your external disk and select your backup. [Here](http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50034.aspx) is a guide for that.

Comment: So I am heading in the right direction I guess. Thanks a lot for the clarifications.